# Issue with IDs containing space in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm dynamically generating tables in ajax success and giving each table an id. This id is equal to the product model's Number.

But in many case product model number contains spaces, due to which it is not generating the ids properly like if the model is 'MU-1 SLD G' then dynamic table looks like this
`<table id="MU-1" g="" sld="">`

So how to handle this situation ?

Comment: while generating dynamic ID you can replace space with _

Comment: Not enough context information... but the best solution would be to just replace the space with a symbol of choice.

Comment: where is the code? add the code because it seems to be offtopic to me. vote for close.

Comment: This doesn't seem related to jQuery but to the generation scheme. One thing is sure : you can't have spaces in id.

Comment: I complete agree with @dystroy. You can not have space in ID. if you need to store it you should consider `data-*` attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDs cannot have spaces in them.

When generating the table content, use a replace function that will change the spaces into "-". When referencing the table rows from the data received from the server, use the same function to generate the valid ID to look for.

A simple example of a function that does this:

```
function replaceAllSpacesWithLines( string ) {
    return string.replace(/ /g, '-');
}
```

So basically when generating the content, iterate over all data coming from the ajax request - assuming this is a json response with some sort of array of elements - and create the table rows by using this function for the ids. For easier reference, you could also se a data attribute for the rows to keep the value of the original id just in case you need it.

For a table row with the key "SOME KEY 1" you could end up with:

```
<tr data-id='SOME KEY 1' id='SOME-KEY-1'> ... data ... </tr>
```

This way, when clicking on the element, you can check the data-id for the real id, and when selecting the row from the logical data, you could regenerate the id, or simply query the dom for the row with the particular data-id.

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can't write a CSS selector for certain elements, then you can fetch them via an alternative method and pass the elements into jQuery directly. For example, with IDs which contain spaces, use the `getElementById` method:

http://jsfiddle.net/cvWt5/

```
<div id="foo bar">Hello</div>
```

And in JS:

```
var element = document.getElementById("foo bar");
jQuery(element).css({ color: "red" });
```

*However*, since spaces in IDs are [not valid HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id), you should avoid using spaces in IDs. A better solution is to change the space characters to non-space characters such as an underscore, `_`, or to use [camelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase#Background%3a_multi-word_identifiers) identifiers instead.

Comment: according to the spec, an ID must not contain space characters. So you should in no circumstance use them! http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much the same link I posted.

Comment: Why do you then write such an answer? It encourages beginners to do nonsense... When I wrote the comment, your edit was not yet present (I know, I wrote it some minutes after your edit, but I didn't refresh the answer until I wrote the comment).

Comment: It is useful to know how to use jQuery with elements that are hard to write CSS selectors for, if the id had dots in it then it would be a pain to write a CSS selector then too. The technique described above is useful in cases like that. And anyway, even though using spaces in IDs is a bad idea, that doesn't mean you _can't_ do it. I dislike telling people that things are impossible instead of explaining the real reasons why they shouldn't.

Comment: I agree with the first part of your comment. But i strongly disagree with the second one. Nonstandard == unsafe - basically the browservendors can change the behaviour the very next day - breaking your code. So never encourage inexperienced users to use quirky behaviour. I took the freedom to adapt your answer accordingly and give you a +1 for the first part of your answer;)